# Can code audits be considered static analysis?

Tags: code-analysis, static-analysis, static-code-analysis, code-auditing

When people talk about static analysis, they usually talk about quality metrics and programming conventions. And seems that code auditing is something apart, since what it finds are bugs and security breaches. When, in theory, both are static analysis (**code audits are made without executing the program, aren't they?** With tools like Findbugs, Coverity, etc.).

So, is code auditing static analysis also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code audits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_audit) is done by humans mostly (with some little help from tools), like any other kind of [audits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audit) (e.g. [financial audits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_audit)). [Code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) is generally done inside the developing team, but code audit is often done by outside persons.

Static [source code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) is done by software [code analysis tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis), and using them is very complex in practice (so in fact the analyzing software tool needs help or expertise from its user and/or will give [false positives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives)).

The [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is a fondamental limitation of source code analysis: no tool can exist to statically detect *every* infinitely looping program (and only them).

You might consider, for analysis of C or C++ code, customizing your GCC compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). Or using [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/), probably by adding [ACSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI/ISO_C_Specification_Language) annotations into your source code (with enough annotations, and on some *limited* classes of C programs, mostly for embedded applications, the tool would be able to *prove* that your code behave well w.r.t. specifications).

But there is [no silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet). Programming is hard (even with tools).

Comment: What about tools like Coverity or Findbugs?

Comment: It depends at how you look at it. A God-like person with infinite wisdom might do code audits differently...

Comment: If you can hire God to do your code audits, you might do better than most of the rest of us.  In the meantime, I only get to use fallible, finite human beings.

Comment: The point is that the halting problem proof supposes that you feed the analyzer with a near copy of itself. How would you feed a human brain with a near copy of itself? I feel that speaking of halting problem for human auditors has no precise meaning, unless you define it precisely.